# Range Slider using Puppeter

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

If I want to apply filters using a range slider at increments of 5% of the width each, how would I go about this.

I tried something similar to here: [How to manipulate mat-slider value using puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510885/how-to-manipulate-mat-slider-value-using-puppeteer/76673831#76673831), but it didn't work.

Trying to do it for a range selector where selected values must be near each other - 5 to 10% intervals. Because of this, it selects the leftmost point to move over each time, rather than moving both left and right towards each other.

Similar behavior can be noticed on the range slider on this page: https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with my open-source Puppeteer wrapper lib (or just steal needed methods from it).

https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai

[Documentation](https://wix-incubator.github.io/bubanai/modules/src.html#dragelementby)

This code works ok with provided slider

```js
import {
  dragElementBy,
  getElement,
  waitForElementNotToBeInViewport,
} from 'bubanai-ng';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node-puppeteer-core';

describe('Drag: dragElementBy()', () => {
  let element;
  let page;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    page = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then((p) => p.newPage());
    await page.goto('https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview');
    element = await getElement(page, 'mat-slider-visual-thumb');
    
    //close pop-up
    const popUpButton = await getElement(
      page,
      '.popup.ng-star-inserted button',
    );
    await popUpButton.click();
    await waitForElementNotToBeInViewport(page, popUpButton);
  });

  it('drags element by specified offsets', async () => {
    const byX = 50;
    await dragElementBy(page, element, byX, 0);
  });
});
```